# Easymock generic matcher got compiling Error in eclipse while can pass build with ant

Tags: java, generics, easymock

I have a method like below:

```
<T extends Resource> Response<T> post(Request<T> request)
```

And tried to mock it:

```
EasyMock.expect(restClient.post(isA(Request.class))).andReturn(response);
```

When I open the file in eclipse, it will mark the *post* with error mark and said : 
The method post(Request) in the type RestClient is not applicable for the arguments (Request)

But it can be build via ant command. I am not sure why eclipse complaint it. The both setting of compiler are 1.8

Comment: Sounds like a typical “Eclipse & Generics (in Java 8)” issue which, of course, disappears as soon as you build using `javac` (via ant). Note that `Request.class` has the type `Class<Request>` (`Request` being a *raw type*), hence, there will be no check whether the generic type of `response` matches.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do something like this instead

```
EasyMock.expect(restClient.post(EasyMock.<Request<Resource>>anyObject())).andReturn(response);
```

This syntax will allow you to fix the type correctly. You don't need an isA since the post method is strongly typed anyway.